# Error in Dansguardian init.d sh script?

Tags: shell

In the `Dansguardian` init.d script there is a function involved in shutdown that looks like:

```
#!/bin/sh
wait_for_pid()
{
 local PID=$1
 local RET=0

if [ $PID -eq 0 ] ; then
    return $RET
fi

# give 60 secs then KILL
local COUNTDOWN=60

while [ -d /proc/${PID} ] && [ $COUNTDOWN -gt 0 ] ; do
    sleep 1
    COUNTDOWN=$[$COUNTDOWN-1]
done

.
.
.
}
```

However, despite it more or less working to shutdown the daemon, it seems to also give an error about the `COUNTDOWN=$[$COUNTDOWN-1]` line .

Is this line correct syntax?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, that doesn't seem to be correct syntax. Try this instead:

```
# COUNTDOWN=60
# COUNTDOWN=$(($COUNTDOWN-1))
# echo $COUNTDOWN
59
```

Comment: Thankyou, yes that has got rid of the "Illegal number" message from my shutdown. It's interesting that the method `COUNTDOWN=$[$COUNTDOWN-1]` works totally fine if script is ran with `bash`, but if ran with `sh` it fails, and only your method gives 59.

Comment: E.g. make a `test.sh`: echo "Trying it the original way"
x=60
x=$[$x-1]
echo $x

echo "Trying it the new way"
y=60
y=$(($y-1))
echo $y". Then try running it as `bash test.sh` and `sh test.sh`.

Comment: In my case it works with `bash test.sh`, but not with `sh test.sh`

Comment: Yes precisely what I get too. The init.d script is set to run with `sh` you see, for whatever reason, hence that's why this line was failing. Thanks for the help getting to bottom of it.